# C++ Resolving conflicts with legacy unnamed namespaces

Tags: c++, clang

I have a large body of legacy code which declares a number of important types. For example:

```
typedef uint32 EventId;
```

I'm currently integrating an excellent new version of 3rd party code (Scaleform) which *has* namespaces, but has conflicting definitions:

```
namespace Scaleform { namespace GFx {
class EventId ...
}}
```

There is code where both definitions are encountered, and I of course get errors:

> error: reference to 'EventId' is ambiguous
>
> note: candidate found by name lookup is 'EventId'
>
> note: candidate found by name lookup is 'Scaleform::GFx::EventId'

(OSX Clang, BTW)

As far as I can tell, I'm kind of SOL, since C++ forbids these sorts of collisions, and I can't (for example) wrap legacy references with something like :

```
using namespace;
```

To force the unnamed namespace.

My only recourse is to rename one of the types so there's no conflict, correct?

Comment: You should be able to dump your legacy code into its own namespace. No, not "using namespace", but a proper namespace declaration. This shouldn't be much more work than slapping `namespace MyNamespace {    [existing contents] }` in your header files and C++ sources. As long as the existing code is well-organized -- all includes come first, then all declarations -- slapping a namespace around the declaration is all that's needed. With many headers/source files this becomes a chore, but it is usually possible to hack up a script to do this. This should be all that's needed. Ditto for C++ source.

Comment: Can't you just qualify the new types? `::EventId` and `Scaleform::GFx::EventId` should not be ambiguous.

Comment: If your problem is what I think it is, https://ideone.com/37hge2 , specifying global namespace `::identifier` should do what you need.

Comment: That should not be ambiguous. What context is the code with the errors. Do you have a `using namespace Scaleform::GFx;` in your code?

Comment: Specifying "::" In front of the anonymous declarations worked! I didn't try it before since other answers on SO implied that once there was a conflict you were SOL, but I'm glad I tried it. Thanks @user4581301!

Comment: Ugh. Spoke too soon:

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Script.h:851:3: error: reference to 'Ptr' is ambiguous
  Ptr                 stringList;             /*pointer to stream of identifiers*/
  ^
/usr/include/MacTypes.h:248:41: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'Ptr'
typedef char *                          Ptr;
                                        ^
(...redacted...)/Src/Kernel/SF_RefCount.h:364:7: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'Scaleform::Ptr'
class Ptr
      ^
I don't have much control over MacTypes.h

Comment: Sounds like you might want to consider what Martin York is hinting at and removing any `using namespace ...` declarations you have cluttering up the global namespace or at least scope them better.

Comment: I don't have _any_ using namespace ... in my code. Scaleform's #includes may have them, but I don't have control over that. Thanks!

Comment: Scaleform sample application headers have `using namespace` declarations, but the headers you should use in your own applications doesn't. Are you doing an `#include` of some of their app headers in your code for some reason?