# C++ Namespace conflicts between 3rd party headers

Tags: c++, namespaces, scaleform

This is related to [another namespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434713).

I'm integrating Scaleform into an OSX C++ application.

I'm getting type conflicts between OSX headers (/usr/include/MacTypes.h) and Scaleform Headers:

```
...other includes...
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:77:
/usr/include/MacTypes.h:249:9: error: reference to 'Ptr' is ambiguous
typedef Ptr *                           Handle;
        ^
/usr/include/MacTypes.h:248:41: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'Ptr'
typedef char *                          Ptr;
                                        ^
.../sf_4.6.33_osx_lib/Include/../Src/Kernel/SF_RefCount.h:364:7: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'Scaleform::Ptr'
class Ptr
      ^
```

I probably don't want to change /usr/include/MacTypes.h :-). And I don't want to go down the path of modifying Scaleform code.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a `using namespace Scaleform;` somewhere? If so, remove it

Comment: What you have here (or in the linked question) is not a conflict but an ambiguity. An ambiguity you seem to have created yourself.

Comment: I don't have a using namespace Scaleform :-(.

Comment: I'm not sure how I created this ambiguity since I authored neither /usr/include/MacTypes.h or SF_Refcount.h?

Comment: @MichaelWilson well it's claiming that `'Scaleform::Ptr` is clashing with `Ptr` (in the global namespace)  Usual way to get that problem is by `using namespace Scaleform;`

Comment: @RichardCritten I agree! But I didn't author either of those libraries and I'm not using any/either of the namespaces.

Comment: What file it is compiling?

Comment: It's compiling one of our source files. MacTypes.h is being included via OSX's coreFoundation.h and CFBase.h.

Comment: Check out other headers and make sure some nincompoop didn't drop a `using namespace Scaleform;` inside one as a booby trap. Generating a pre-processed file (-E option in gcc) may help.

Comment: It may be worth filing a bug report requesting that the compiler messages in such cases inform you where the symbol was brought into the namespace. (It shows the line where `Scaleform::Ptr` was defined, but it ought to show where that was imported into the global namespace.)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to define your own namespace and put one of the conflicting #include statements in the new namespace. For example, if you determine that including the statement

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
```

in your code leads to the error you've described, then put that statement in a new namespace. For example,

```
namespace carbon {
    #include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
}
```

You'll then need to preface any references to tokens needing that header with the namespace you've created. For example,

```
carbon::VoiceSpec v;
carbon::VoiceSpec *vspec = &v;
carbon::OSErr theErr = carbon::noErr;
carbon::SInt16 vindex;
carbon::VoiceDescription vdesc;
```

Kudos to https://apple-dev.groups.io/g/xcode/topic/76179751 for having tipped me off to the solution.